Priors in brms are not working as I expect
I'm new to Bayesian Statistics, and I'm trying to fit a simple Linear Regression using brms and setting priors manually to each parameter, but it does not work as I expect
Here is my code
data_2 <- structure(list(YearsExperience = c(1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 2, 2.2, 2.9, 3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.7, 3.9, 4, 4, 4.1, 4.5, 4.9, 5.1, 5.3, 5.9, 6, 
6.8, 7.1, 7.9, 8.2, 8.7, 9, 9.5, 9.6, 10.3, 10.5), Salary = c(39343L, 
46205L, 37731L, 43525L, 39891L, 56642L, 60150L, 54445L, 64445L, 
57189L, 63218L, 55794L, 56957L, 57081L, 61111L, 67938L, 66029L, 
83088L, 81363L, 93940L, 91738L, 98273L, 101302L, 113812L, 109431L, 
105582L, 116969L, 112635L, 122391L, 121872L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))

priors <- c(
  set_prior("normal(28700, 2000)", class = "Intercept"),
  set_prior("normal(9006, 1000)", class = "b", 
              coef = "YearsExperience"),
  set_prior("normal(0, 2000)", class = "sigma", lb = 0) 
)

fit_brms <- brm(Salary ~ YearsExperience, data = data_2, prior=priors)

However, when I plot the chains, there are negative values for the Intercept, for example, when the prior distribution is far from the negative values. And it is not the case that the priors I set are completely inaccurate.

If I fit using the default priors, it works well.

The intercept prior for brms can a bit confusing, start by reading the section "Parameterization of the population-level intercept" in ?brms::brmsformula. Try using Salary ~ 0 + Intercept + YearsExperience and see if that solves the issue.

From ?brmsformula:

Parameterization of the population-level intercept
By default, the population-level intercept (if incorporated) is
estimated separately and not as part of population-level parameter
vector b As a result, priors on the intercept also have to be
specified separately. Furthermore, to increase sampling efficiency,
the population-level design matrix X is centered around its column
means X_means if the intercept is incorporated. This leads to a
temporary bias in the intercept equal to <X_means, b>, where <,> is
the scalar product. The bias is corrected after fitting the model, but
be aware that you are effectively defining a prior on the intercept of
the centered design matrix not on the real intercept. You can turn off
this special handling of the intercept by setting argument center to
FALSE. For more details on setting priors on population-level
intercepts, see set_prior.
This behavior can be avoided by using the reserved (and internally
generated) variable Intercept. Instead of y ~ x, you may write y ~ 0 +
Intercept + x. This way, priors can be defined on the real intercept,
directly. In addition, the intercept is just treated as an ordinary
population-level effect and thus priors defined on b will also apply
to it. Note that this parameterization may be less efficient than the
default parameterization discussed above.

See this very rough image (note swapped colors) of an idea what happened. You set the prior to the intercept after mean centering of the predictors. This pushes the intercept down a lot. Using the (less efficient) alternative intercept gives the correct fit.

As said, you can use the 0 + Intercept formulation to get around this. But, it is often actually quite convenient to set the prior for the intercept this way, since you only have to reason about the population mean, without having to take into account the slopes.
Some rough code:
library(brms)
library(ggdist)
library(ggplot2)

priors <- c(
  set_prior("normal(28700, 2000)", class = "Intercept"),
  set_prior(
    "normal(9006, 1000)", class = "b", 
    coef = "YearsExperience"
  ),
  set_prior("normal(0, 2000)", class = "sigma", lb = 0) 
)

fit_brms <- brm(Salary ~ YearsExperience, data = data_2, prior  =priors)

priors2 <- c(
  set_prior("normal(28700, 2000)", class = "b", coef = "Intercept"),
  set_prior(
    "normal(9006, 1000)", class = "b", 
    coef = "YearsExperience"
  ),
  set_prior("normal(0, 2000)", class = "sigma", lb = 0) 
)
fit_brms2 <- brm(
  Salary ~ 0 + Intercept + YearsExperience, 
  data = data_2, 
  prior = priors2
)

nd <- data.frame(YearsExperience = seq(
  min(data_2$YearsExperience), 
  max(data_2$YearsExperience), 
  l = 100
))

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(YearsExperience, Salary), data_2) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = c(0, mean(data_2$YearsExperience)))) +
  geom_line(
aes(nd$YearsExperience, Estimate, color = 'the incorrect fit'), 
    data = predict(fit_brms, nd)
  ) +
  geom_line(
    aes(nd$YearsExperience, Estimate, color = 'the correct fit'), 
data = predict(fit_brms2, nd)
  ) +
  stat_halfeye(aes(
x = 0, 
ydist = parse_dist("normal(28700, 2000)")[[3]],
fill = 'your intended prior'
  )) +
  stat_halfeye(aes(
x = mean(data_2$YearsExperience), 
    ydist = parse_dist("normal(28700, 2000)")[[3]],
    fill = 'your actual prior'
  )) +
  theme_classic()

